# Defining a variable in a module and returning it (NodeJs)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

*I have a code to insert user data to the database like in following;*

```
exports.signup = function (data) {
    const mongodb = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    var rcode;    
    const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
    mongodb.connect(url,(err,db) => {
        if(err) rcode = 24
        var dbo = db.db('project');
        dbo.collection('users').insertOne(data, (err, dres) => {
            if (err) rcode = 24
            else rcode = 25
            db.close;
        })  
    })

    console.log(rcode) // It returns 'undefined'
    return rcode;
}
```

I try to return a number about the success of the process. But I get the result of 'undefined' every time. How can I solve this issue most accurately?

-- I've comprehended the root of the issue, that's asynchronous but I couldn't find a way to get that number. Can you give me a short example and explanation?

Answer (score 0):

*mongodb.connect* and *dbo.collection('users').insertOne* are async calls.
You need to use promise to handle it.

> Approach 1: new Promise((resolve, reject) => {})

```
exports.signup = function (data) {
    const mongodb = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    var rcode;    
    const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

mongodb.connect(url,(err,db) => {
    if(err)  resolve(24) // here you can use reject('error')
    var dbo = db.db('project');
    dbo.collection('users').insertOne(data, (err, dres) => {
        if (err) rcode = 24
        else rcode =25
        resolve(rcode);
        db.close;
    })  
})

});
}
```

> Approach 2: Deferred Promise

You can refer my blog on promises:
[Asynchronous programming with node.js](https://shivaji-mutkule.blogspot.com/2015/04/asynchronous-programming-with-node-js.html)

Your code could be roughly:

```
// add dependency for q library
var Q = require('q');
exports.signup = function (data) {
    const mongodb = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    var rcode;    
    const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";

    var defered = Q.defer();

    mongodb.connect(url,(err,db) => {
        if(err)  defered.resolve(24) // here you can use defered.reject('error')
        var dbo = db.db('project');
        dbo.collection('users').insertOne(data, (err, dres) => {
            if (err) rcode = 24
            else rcode =25
            defered.resolve(rcode)
            db.close;
        })  
    })

    return defered.promise;
}
```

> Approach 3:

You can use async/await from ES6

Comment: Firstly thanks so much for this your multiple-choice answer. I keep the second approach as the last chance because I try to include modules as less as possible. I tried the first one and I had printed the result with console.log and it returned something like "Promise { <pending> }". What is this?

Comment: You need to do changes at function caller side too like signup().then((rcode) => console.log(rcode));